# How to build a GTK4 project using CMake on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, cmake, gtk, msys2

I used the following CMake code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(tarost VERSION 1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GTK REQUIRED gtk4-win32)

aux_source_directory(src SRCDIR)
add_executable(tarost ${SRCDIR})
target_link_libraries(tarost ${GTK3_LIBRARY_DIRS})

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

CMake configured for MinGW makefiles

Got the following output:

```
The C compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
Check for working C compiler: D:/ProgFiles/MSYS64/usr/bin/gcc.exe
Check for working C compiler: D:/ProgFiles/MSYS64/usr/bin/gcc.exe - works
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
Check for working CXX compiler: D:/ProgFiles/MSYS64/usr/bin/g++.exe
Check for working CXX compiler: D:/ProgFiles/MSYS64/usr/bin/g++.exe - works
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
Found PkgConfig: D:/ProgFiles/MSYS64/usr/bin/pkg-config.exe (found version "1.8.0") 
Checking for module 'gtk4-win32'
  Package 'gtk4-win32', required by 'virtual:world', not found
CMake Error at D:/ProgFiles/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:605 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  D:/ProgFiles/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:827 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (pkg_check_modules)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/Michael/Coding/c/tarost/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "D:/Michael/Coding/c/tarost/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

It seems that CMake cannot find `gtk4-win32` using pkg-config. However, I manually invoked `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk4-win32` in MSYS64 shell and I am sure it is properly installed:

```
-ID:/ProgFiles/MSYS64/mingw64/include/gtk-4.0 -ID:/ProgFiles/MSYS64/mingw64/include/pango-1.0 -ID:/ProgFiles/MSYS64/mingw64/include -ID:/ProgFiles/MSYS64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0 -ID:/ProgFiles/MSYS64/mingw64/lib/glib-2.0/include -ID:/ProgFiles/MSYS64/mingw64/include/harfbuzz -ID:/ProgFiles/MSYS64/mingw64/include/freetype2 -ID:/ProgFiles/MSYS64/mingw64/include/libpng16 -ID:/ProgFiles/MSYS64/mingw64/include/fribidi -ID:/ProgFiles/MSYS64/mingw64/include/cairo -ID:/ProgFiles/MSYS64/mingw64/include/lzo -ID:/ProgFiles/MSYS64/mingw64/include/pixman-1 -ID:/ProgFiles/MSYS64/mingw64/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -ID:/ProgFiles/MSYS64/mingw64/include/graphene-1.0 
-ID:/ProgFiles/MSYS64/mingw64/lib/graphene-1.0/include -mfpmath=sse -msse -msse2 -mms-bitfields -LD:/ProgFiles/MSYS64/mingw64/lib -lgtk-4 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lharfbuzz -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgraphene-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

Comment: Does any of the files `CMakeOutput.log` or `CMakeError.log` show more details about the failed check for the package? Is it correct that you check for gtk4-win**32** while the result shows MSYS**64** and mingw**64** ?

Comment: The fact that `/usr` is mentioned in the log is extremely suspicious. From what shell do you invoke CMake and pkg-config, are those different shells? You probably want the `MINGW64` MSYS2 shell (as indicated by magenta text in the terminal prompt).

Comment: I executed that in msys64. @HolyBlackCat

Comment: p.s. I later realized that CMake is actually using gcc in the `/usr/bin` folder but not the `/mingw64` one. Thus I removed gcc and generated Mingw makefile again. This time CMake was looking for gcc in `/mingw64` now (this time CMake found GCC 12.1.0). However it seems that CMake is using pkg-config in `/usr/bin` by default. How can I change pkg-config to the one in `/mingw64`? (using cmake-gui)

Comment: *"I executed that in msys64"* There is no such environment. There are `MSYS`, `MINGW64`, `UCRT64`, etc. Please be more specific, from what terminal/shell did you run pkg-config and CMake? Are those the same shell? Or did you use CMake not from a terminal, but from a GUI? Did you add anything to PATH?

Comment: CMake finding both `/mingw64/bin/gcc` and `/usr/bin/gcc` but giving preference to the latter is extremely weird. MSYS2 puts the former earlier in the PATH, so it should get preference, unless you are setting PATH manually?

Comment: correction: `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk4-win32` was executed in the MinGW64 shell. I was running pkg-config from the MinGW64 shell and CMake from cmake-gui. Probably I need to run CMake from MinGW64 shell?